# How to open Network PC there folders in Net Beans by open project option

Tags: netbeans

I have Ubuntu 13.04, installed NetBeans 7.3.1 php, for php development, all file are save in network pc, I can bookmark and open network pc file and folder easy, but when I'm using netbeans and when I try to open network pc or bookmark which I saved earlier there no option coming only showing own pc folder like home, opt, var, usr, but no network or bookmark option.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 13.10 is located in

```
/run/user/USERNAME/1000/gvfs/SHARENAME
```

Answer (score 2):

When using an application that doesn't use the native open/save file dialog, the shortcuts to network locations are not shown and you'll need to use the full (and ugly) path to these files.

After you've used the normal file browser to connect to a network share (I'm assuming you mean a windows/SMB shared folder), you'll be able to access it from other programs from:

Ubuntu 12.04

```
/home/USERNAME/.gvfs/SHARENAME
```

Ubuntu 12.10-13.04

```
/run/user/USERNAME/gvfs/SHARENAME
```